# Changing CSS with DOM getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, css, dom, getelementsbyname

I am trying to make changed to CSS with the DOM in JS, I have succeeded with changing the HTML attributes but not the CSS attributes. It seems that CSS is not affected by this particular DOM.

Code looks like this...

```
<style>
    #circle1{

            width: 50px !important;
            height: 50px !important;
            position: absolute !important;
            top: 200px !important;
            left: 405px !important;
            background: black !important;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 50px !important;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 50px !important;
            border-top-left-radius: 50px !important;
            border-top-right-radius: 50px !important;
            z-index: 10 !important;
            visibility: hidden !important;

    }


    </style>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showCircle(){
    document.getElementsByName ("circle").style.visibility="visible";  
}

</script>
<div id="circle1" name="circle"></div>

<input type="button" onclick="showCircle()" value="show circle with display property">
</body>
```

Comment: Javascript cannot override `!important` very easily, and it doesn't seem to be necessary for your case to have the important rule.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
function showCircle(){
    document.getElementsByName("circle")[0].style.visibility="visible";  
}
```

and remove `!important` from `css` class for visibility attribute

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/frjS3/)

Comment: Your absolutely right the !important was my biggest issue. I removed it from the code and was able to then move to the next stage of testing for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByName` returns a `NodeList` of elements. If you want the first element, say so:

```
document.getElementsByName("circle")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
```

But if you only have one, why not just use the `id`? `<div>`s shouldn't really have `name`s anyways...

```
document.getElementById('circle').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

If there *are* many, you might consider using classes instead. (And classes for the visibility might be better, too!)

Finally, stop making all your styles `!important` for no good reason. There is almost never a good reason to make any rules important, and it can make everything a mess of `!important` when specificity would have made things much nicer. If you just threw those in to try and fix something... that made it worse.

Comment: Yes I learned after posting that the !important was an area of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You've set everything as `!important`. That takes precedence over inline styles. The quickest solution would be to set `style.visibility = 'visible!important'`, or you could unimportant the importants.

Comment: Yup it was the crux of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all for your suggestions, the biggest problem was the !important over-riding most of the JS. I switched to using display and removed the !important. Code as follows. I ended using another function to hide the divs and a case to show them as the random generator made the input as to which case was visible.

```
document.getElementById("circle1").style.display = "block";
```